# Count occurrence of a max value within aggregation

Tags: python, dataframe, count, conditional-statements, aggregation

I have a table like this:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2 |
| John | 8 |
| John | 8 |
| John | 8 |
| Robert | 5 |
| Robert | 5 |
| Robert | 1 |
| Carl | 8 |
| Carl | 7 |

Now what I want is to aggregate this DataFrame by **Column1** and get the **max** value as well as to **count** how many times does the given **max value** occurs for every group.

So the output should look like this:

| Column1 | Max | Count_of_Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 8 | 3 |
| Robert | 5 | 2 |
| Carl | 8 | 1 |

I've been trying to do something like this:

```
def Max_Count(x):
       a = df.loc[x.index]
       return a.loc[a['Column2'] == a['Column2'].max(), 'Column2'].count()

df.groupby(["Column1"]).agg({'Column2': ["max", Max_Count]}).reset_index()
```

But it's not really working :(

What would be the way get the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby('Column1').agg({
    'Column2': [max, lambda x: (x==max(x)).sum()]
}).rename(columns={'max': 'Max', '<lambda_0>': 'Count_of_Max'})
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! I tried this on the given in the question data and it worked fine. However, when I test it on another data, I get the wrong result for Carl. It says max value is 5, when it should be 7. Is it the case for you as well?
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [8, 8, 8, 3, 7, 7, 1, 5, 7], 'Column2': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', "Robert",  "Robert",  "Robert", "Carl", "Carl"]})

Comment: @Sergei yeah, `Counter.most_used()` doesn't handle ties. Added a workaround

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem with the ties, because:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [3, 8, 8, 8, 7, 5, 1, 90000, 5, 5], 'Column2': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', "Robert",  "Robert",  "Robert", "Carl", "Carl", "Carl"]})
That one still, gives 5 as max value for Carl. O_O

Comment: @Sergei argh, I glanced over the question too fast - my answer shows how to get most common value instead of max. Fixed, what you want is actually quite a bit easier